# JavaScript dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have senerio, where I need to render my HTML page by using dynamic JavaScript.

I am using loadScript function to load external JavaScript and passing callback funtion. In my HTML page , I am loading this script for my header.
My header section is working perfectly after the script is loaded and I my head section I can see my new script.

However , when I am trying to use the variables from this script its undefined.

```
function loadScript(url,callback){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.id="acvDataRequest";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            alert(dataHeader) // I CAN SEE MY OBJECT FROM LOADED SCRIPT
            callback();
        };
    }
    script.src = url;
    alert(dataHeader);         // IT SAYS UNDEFINED
}
```

calling a script using :

```
var actionName ="JSONdata/json.js";
loadScript(actionName,mergeTemplateJSONScript);
```

Please advice , why i can't see my variables even if my script is there.
Inside script.onload , I am able to see my variable but not outside

Comment: On might ask why you're using a manual loadScript function when you have jQuery and can just use `jQuery.getScript()`?

Answer (score 1):

What you assign:

```
script.src = url;
```

that just starts the loading of the dynamic script.  When you call the second `alert()` on the very next line your script has not yet loaded (it is loading in the background at that point).  You can only reliably access the variables from the newly loaded script from within the `onload` handler or in some function called from the onload handler.

Keep in mind that the dynamic loading of scripts is asynchronous.  That means it happens in the background while other scripts keep running (thus your second `alert()` runs before the script has finished).  And, then the script finishes loading **some time later** and when it does the `onload` handler is called.

So, when you dynamically load scripts, all code that uses those scripts needs to either be in the onload handler, in some function called from the onload handler or guarenteed not to execute until some time later (such as in an event handler that you're sure won't happen before the script finishes loading).

To explain further, I've added some annotations to your code:

```
function loadScript(url,callback){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.id="acvDataRequest";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            // ** your script is now loaded here **
            alert(dataHeader) // I CAN SEE MY OBJECT FROM LOADED SCRIPT
            callback();
        };
    }
    script.src = url;
    // ** your script is in the process of loading here and has likely not completed **
    alert(dataHeader);         // IT SAYS UNDEFINED
}
```

Comment: but what i want is I need to use the variables from this script. So you mean I should prefer synchronous loading? But how to do that?

Comment: @user2985842 - You either put the code that uses the script in your callback (that's what the callback is for) or you stop using dynamic loading and use synchronous loading.  Async works a particular way in Javascript and you either code that way or stop using async operations.  There is no way to write synchronously with an async loading operation.

Comment: do you any example of Synch call ?

Comment: @user2985842 - I would have to see your larger context of what problem you're trying to solve.  A `<script>` tag that is present in the original HTML of your page is synchronously loaded.  A `<script>` tag that is inserted with `document.write()` during the initial load of the JS code in the page (before the document has been fully loaded) is synchronous.  Everything other way to load JS programmatically is asynchronous.  Why is it a big deal to just put the code that references your script in the callback function?  That's how it dynamic loading is supposed to work.

Comment: actually in my context , Inside my header tag i am calling <script>generateHeader();</script> , This generateHeader function is calling loadScript function (as mentioned in post) and script is loaded. I am passing a function parameter to execute callback. Till , this point I am fine. Problem occurs because In my body I am using <script>generateBody();</script>. This requires the same script variables which were added during the header script loading. I dont want to make same loadScript call for my body section. But when I am trying to use variables inside my generateBody() , I m unabl to get

Comment: @user2985842 - sorry, but that brief explanation doesn't explain what actual problem you're trying to solve.  You'd have to show the actual code (in your question where it can be properly formatted) and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: In short , I don't want to make http request for my body section to grap same script which is added by header.

Comment: @user2985842 - then include the script with a `<script>` tag in your actual HTML document. I don't understand what the real problem is that you're trying to solve. Until you describe that in your question, we probably can't help you further. You may want to read about the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which is what you're doing here. You're asking about problems with your attempted solution rather than describing the actual problem. If you're going down the wrong solution path and we don't know what the actual problem is, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The line `script.src = url;` triggers the loading of the script file. If you call alert immediately after it your external script has not been loaded yet. You can only access variables from the json once the `onreadystatechange` or `onload` functions have been called.

What you should do is using it like this:

```
var actionName ="JSONdata/json.js";
loadScript(actionName,function(){
    alert(dataHeader);
});
```

Comment: How i can use the variable in this case. Do I need to have synchronous call?